# Как центрировать и обрезать блок

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

Может кто подскажет какие есть варианты центрировать блок.

У меня есть компонент с тремя блоками: первый и третий должны быть прижаты к левому и правому краю соответственно, а второй блок необходимо центрировать по родителю. Второй блок должен быть обрезан, если он не помещается в доступную ширину экрана, при этом он не должен перекрывать первый и третий блоки. Я пытался использовать CSS Grid и вычисление размеров блоков для установки ширины, но возникает задержка при рендеринге, в результате чего блоки сначала отображаются неправильно, а затем корректируются. Какие есть альтернативные способы решения этой задачи?

Comment: лучше добавьте код, не скрин экрана, а код, и стили также, так будет понятно для других, простое описание проблемы не дает возможность понять в чем ошибка

Comment: `Я пытался использовать CSS Grid ` **`и вычисление размеров блоков для установки ширины`** grid'у не нужны вычисления. дайте контейнеру `{display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;}` а среднему `{overflow: auto}` и в общем то всё! грид все сам вычислит.